# Plotting multiple lines over 3 look back dates for stock % change

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plotly

I have been trying to find a way to get python to ready my `csv`. Take the values that are in the date columns (`3months | 6months | 12months`) and plot it onto a graph however I have been struggling to find resources and have no previous experience with python.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

I have already been able to get python to read a simple csv with little values in however **I cannot figure out a way to show a line for each of these shares over the look back dates**. Here is my csv format.

```
ticker, 3months, 6months, 12months  
appl, -12, 16, 24  
tsla, 9, 10, 7  
amzn, -7, 14, 36
```

I am trying to read the csv and output it into a graph like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python's matplotlib library can do this for you.  Here's a quick example:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> apple = [-12,16,24]
>>> tesla = [9,10,7]
>>> amazon = [-7,14,36]
>>> months = [3,6,12]
>>> plt.plot(months, apple, color='blue')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0E5CD6F0>]
>>> plt.plot(months, tesla, color='orange')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0E5CDAF0>]
>>> plt.plot(months, amazon, color='green')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0E5CDBB0>]
>>> plt.show()
```

This gives you a plot similar to the one you showed.

Again, this is just a basic example.  You can read up on the other matplotlib functions to add things like legends, axis labels, save the graph to a file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` and `matplotlib` will allow you to do this quickly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/csv/', index_col='ticker').transpose()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

df.plot(ax=ax)
```